# Is it possible in <WINDOWS - SINGLE LANGUAGE> version to add other language keyboard layout?

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, input-languages

During Windows installation, there are multiple choices:

Windows XYZ
Windows XYZ - N
Windows XYZ - Single Language

they are described [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install-winpc/difference-between-home-edition-and-home-single/7e567265-dabd-4336-b229-091e9234e8a5). However, it is not clear:

1. if we choose English, can we add other language Keyboard Layout?  (I don't need installing whole Language-pack. I mean only Keyboard Layout.)
2. I doubt it will also necessitate Language pack to read websites in other languages, is it correct?  or with SL version, it can still read all other languages characters on web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if we choose English, can we add other language Keyboard Layout?

**Windows 10 Single Language does not allow any additional language packs to be installed.**  However, you can install multiple keyboards for a single language, within Settings -> Languages

Source: [Manage the input and display language settings in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/manage-the-input-and-display-language-settings-in-windows-10-12a10cb4-8626-9b77-0ccb-5013e0c7c7a2)

> I doubt it will also necessitate Language pack to read websites in other languages, is it correct?

There is no correlation to the language displayed on a website to that of the display language of Windows.

> with SL version, it can still read all other languages characters on web?

Windows 10 Single Language only prevents you from installing additional language packs.